# How to see which header files were used for gcc/g++ compilation

Tags: compilation, g++, header-files, cross-compiling

I have two binaries that were simple c++ programs compiled on a Linux machine. The first binary - call it my_native_prog - uses the build tools (g++, as, etc.), libraries, and headers that come standard on the build machine. The second binary - call it my_toolchain_prog - uses the build tools from a toolchain which has different versions of all the same build tools.

How can I confirm that my_toolchain_prog was correctly compiled with the toolchain's headers/libraries and not the ones that are local to the build machine?

The purpose of the toolchain is to cross compile the code for a specific Linux version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `my_toolchain_prog` was built with debug info then it might include the paths to the headers it used, but if there's no debug info there is no way to find what headers were used from compiled code.

You could run `ldd my_toolchain_prog` which will show you the shared library dependencies and that might show which version of `libstdc++.so` the binary was linked to, which *usually* indicates which toolchain it was built with (it's possible to override things so that e.g. you build with an older GCC and link to the library from a newer one, but that would be unusual)